# Add params before submit form ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, submit

It's possible to add some parameters before submit an form?

My problem is that I need to send the ticket id to my payment controller.

A possibility is to send it through an hidden input field, but there's any other secure way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**The process of buying a ticket**
0) Select the event
1) User select the kind of ticket he wants to buy.
2) User add his personal information 
3) Finally the Checkout  (payment controller)

Comment: Will you send your entire form to a controller and this additional parameter to another?

Comment: Not really, I'll process all the information on payment controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are generating a ticket id which you need in the following form submit. Yes **its better to keep it in hidden variable** in form.

But apart from that you can **store the generated ticket id in session** and can destroy after using it.

If this ticket id is unique for a particular session at a time, then you can **store it in database with a key of session id** and can retrieve and clear the id when form is submitted.

If it is possible, then **generate the ticket id when the form will be submitted**. In this way no question of storing the ticket id in hidden variable or session or database.

Actually there might be lots of other ways but **for a complete and specific suggestion please share some more** of your scenario.

---

**Update:**

Based on your update, I think you need to maintain a `running_transactions` table.

It will have

- `event_id` (pointing to the selected event)
- `ticket_type_id` (pointing to the type of ticket user wants to buy)
- `ticket_id` (an unique id generated by your algorithm)
- `person_details` (pointing to details provided by the user)
- and so on ( may include other payment or transaction status related information)
- **`id`**: the unique identifier of this table.

Now on starting up the buying process

- Create a `running_transaction` entry which will be almost empty.
- Save the id of this table in the session. So for every subsequent request you will find the corresponding `running_transaction` entry by this id.
- This entry will be updated with more values in each phase of buying the ticket. Like, *after "step 1" you will have a ticket id*.
- Eventually when the ticket will be bought successfully and you will receive the payment confirmation, you will mark this `running_transaction` as `completed`.

Probably you already have something to track these information, so you can accommodate the above way in that table also. Perhaps you will find better names than what I provided :)

Comment: Actually the ticket it's not created until the payment its done, so i don't really know how to merge those params to don't loose the event id and the ticket id. My first thought was to do it by hidden fields but i don't want that a user can hack those values. So it will be more secure to add it on his current session?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Now I  have a more clear vision of how to do it, but I think making the rollback of everything (for don't get trash on my db) will be a kind of challenging, if the user left before finish the transaction.

Comment: its easy... first of all, you need to ensure that ticket buying process should be completed within a specific amount of time. Say one hour or one day as your preference. Use a timestamp column for that. Now cron job might run which will clean up all the transactions that not **completed** and time limit is expired.

Comment: Thanks! making some investigation I found the gem whenever and i think with this it will be possible to schedule my rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in an app that I have.

```
<td><%= @competencys[index].name %></td>
<%= f.hidden_field :student_id %>
<td>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, '4' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :rating_id, :value => @competencys[index].ratings[0].id %>
  <%= @competencys[index].ratings[0].description %>
</td>
```

This may be a little tough to follow, but in this instance I am creating a result, which has a student_id field, and a rating_id field. In the case of the student_id, this field is already associated with the :student_id symbol(from the controller), so I am just assigning it 'under the covers' with the f.hidden_field

In the case of rating_id, I was not able to assign it in the controller, and needed to do it 'on the fly', hence the code...

```
<%= f.hidden_field :rating_id, :value => @competencys[index].ratings[1].id %>
```

So here you can see I am using this :value symbol to directly assign the rating_id in the view. Not sure if this helps, but thought I would share. Good luck!